# Alternate access mappings http:// and https://

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, alternate-access-mapping, https

I have developed SharePoint application with default access mappings with url: http://example.sp.com where i deployed all my solution packages. In alternate access mappings i add a new url https://example.sp.com with internet zone. I can access my sharepoint web application http://example.sp.com (default zone). But when i try to access https://example.sp.com (internet zone), i get following error:

```
This page can't be displayed
Make sure the web address is correct. 
Look for the page with your search engine. 
Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

is something wrong with alternate access mappings or https:// protocol?
any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

In order to https Url work, please make sure following things.

- SSL Certificate added to the Web front end servers
- Bind the SSL certs to Web App
- Update the Https url in AAM.

Answer (score 3):

Also note that adding a new AAM does not automatically create the IIS bindings.

You will need to configure them manually (select the web site in IIS and add the new binding) as they are only created if you extend the web application (which would probably be better in your case).